# How to handle data lost when restart instance

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, grafana

I deployed Grafana via Docker container on GCP compute engine but when I restart this instance I found that all data will lost. How to solve this problem?

```dockerfile
# Use the official Grafana base image
FROM grafana/grafana:latest

ENV GF_SECURITY_ADMIN_USER=admin
ENV GF_SECURITY_ADMIN_PASSWORD=admin
# Create a volume for Grafana data
VOLUME /var/lib/grafana

# Expose Grafana port
EXPOSE 3000
```

Comment: Docker [volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/) enable you to persist data between container restarts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you deployed Grafana via a Docker container on a Google Cloud Platform (GCP) Compute Engine instance and you're losing data when the instance is restarted, it's likely because the data is stored within the container itself, which doesn't persist across container restarts. To solve this problem and ensure that your Grafana data is persistent, you should consider using external storage or volumes for Grafana.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I see. thank you so much